# Style checkbox , set background color on checked to 70% inside the window

Tags: css, checkbox

I could use some help with the styling of my checkbox field. Right now, I made some custom css myself, and it work very well. Now I just need to have a checked mark inside the checkbox window.

**Code so far:**

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 30px; /*Desired width*/
    height: 30px; /*Desired height*/
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #fcfbfb;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    color: black;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    background-color: #002B45;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:focus {
    outline: 0 none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

**Html code:**

```
<div class="column small-12">
  <div class="checkbox">                             
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "sbw_checkbox" })
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "sbw_label" })
  </div>  
</div>
```

Have made some pictures so you can see how it looks.. and what I'm trying to achive.

This is when its not checked.

[image: Not checked]

This is when its checked.

[image]

This is what I'm trying to create.

[image]

Can any see, or have something I can try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try adding some styles using `:before`

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked:before {
    content: '';
    background: #002B45;
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Make sure to also add `position: relative` to the `input[type="checkbox"]:checked` style so that it will center within the checkbox.

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hunter377/4ku53hwy/).

Comment: See.. this is just what I was looking for. Thanks alot for your help and Happy New Year to you.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help! :)

Comment: to addition Hunter's great answer. you don't need transform here. you can remove that and simply change location to `left: 25%;
    top: 25%;`

Comment: I'm a bit of a perfectionist, so I like to use the transform because it gets an exact center. If you change it in the fiddle to 25%, you can see that the centering is a bit off.

Comment: i did pixel count. it is all even on my side. maybe something off with your screen stretch?

Comment: No, it is a bit off, but here is why my solution is better for exact centering. If you where to make the inner box smaller (let's say 10x10 instead of 15x15) and do it your way, it would not center the box. Your way will only work if the inner box is exactly half the size of the containing box. This is what your solution does: https://jsfiddle.net/pkaL4185/

Comment: i see your point. you are right in that case. can you check also why box shadow disappears after click?

Comment: Because in his code under `input[type="checkbox"]:focus` he sets `box-shadow` to `none`...